# How to parse the response of fetch as JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

My react code:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/getnames")
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
  alert("data: "+data);
  alert("index: "+data.indexOf(value));
  data.indexOf(value) === -1 ? callback() : callback("DuplicateName")
})
```

if array is `["abc","def"]` then `data.indexOf("a")` is > `-1`. Why? How to resolve this

> What I want is exact match. how to accomplish that?

Comment: Because `data` is a **string** that contains the character `a` (more specifically at index 3). What other result do you expect?

Comment: @FelixKling updated ques

Comment: *"if array is ["abc","def"]"* That's the flaw right here. `data` is not an array, it's a string. Your question should be: How to parse the response of `fetch` as JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling Can you explain why

Comment: Why what exactly?

Comment: @FelixKling oh ok so you are saying io i di response.json() then ill get array right?... FYI Update question heading please remove the downvote

Comment: Yes. But I cannot remove something that I haven't done `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the response is JSON, you have to parse it. You should use `response.json()` method instead of `response.text()`:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/getnames")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
  alert("data: "+data);
  alert("index: "+data.indexOf(value));
  data.indexOf(value)===-1?callback():callback("DuplicateName")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `response.text()`, you need to write `response.json()` to test for the exact match, since `reponse.text()` will give you `data` as `string` while, `response.json()` will return the `data` to be an `array`

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/getnames")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
  alert("data: "+data);
  alert("index: "+data.indexOf(value));
  data.indexOf(value)===-1?callback():callback("DuplicateName")
})
```